# Changing Imageview's image continuously is giving memrory warning in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have to change image of image view continuously. But while changing i got memory warning and crash.

Comment: Can you add some code as well, how you are changing image?

Comment: You need to show code. But changing an image "continuously" smells like an animation hack. If animation is what you are attempting, you're barking up the wrong tree entirely.

Comment: @ConradShultz Then it would be better if you could kindly suggest us with the right approach to achieve it. How to continuously change UIImageView image,say for ex: in my case I want to glow on and off,on and off the lights(flashing). So without animation, how to do it :/

Answer (score 3):

As I am doing the something in my application, You just put all the images in a single array. you can try as images are changes based on the duration. You can do..

```
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"];
UIImage *img3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"];
UIImage *img4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"];
UIImage *img5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"];

animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,nil];
[imgView setAnimationImages:animationImages];
[imgView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
[imgView startAnimating];
```

and then apply the [imgView stopAnimaiton] where you want to stop this effect. It works fine for me.